# Is it possible to block one cookie on a domain

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Is it possible to block one cookie on a domain, without blocking all cookies on that domain? (I want to block the tracking cookies, without blocking the cookies that are required for functionality.) I'm using Chrome on Windows.

I'm aware of [Block cookies by name, not by site, in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/224930/firefox-how-to-block-cookies-by-name-not-by-site) but the answers given don't directly address the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) Chrome extension allows to block one cookie for the specific domain:

[image: blocked cookie]

Answer (score 0):

[StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) chrome extension allows blocking one cookie or multiple cookies depending on how many cookies user has selected.

[image]

You can also block a specific cookie by clicking the ellipsis icon (three-dots icon) as below:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You can block all the cookies from site by going into Chrome setting.
Then click on "Cookies and other site site data".
Scroll all the way to the bottom and click on "Sites that can never use cookies".
Now enter "twitter.com" and save.

You shouldn't have any problems now, but in case, you might need to reboot either Chrome or your computer.

Comment: Question pretty explicitly asks about blocking specific cookies, not all cookies.