# how to block a specific cookie from a specific site

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, cookies

- *Relevant question, but does not answer my question: [Block cookies by name, not by site, in Firefox](https://superuser.com/q/224930/290037) - This is too specific about Google Analytics*

I have started getting quite active on StackOverflow recently, so I've been opening fairly many links to http://jsfiddle.net, but since I'd need to resize the panels regularly to see the specific code posted in the way the code was intended, I usually end up with some pretty weird configurations for the panels. Because I would prefer not having to resize the windows to a more normal setting every time, I would like to block the `window_sizes` cookie from jsfiddle, but when I tried googling for how to block a single cookie from a specific site, I could find nothing.

I've also tried checking the settings for both Chrome and Firefox, but neither have the option to block a specific cookie, only to block certain domains.

I'm mostly wondering on how to block this specific cookie in Chrome (which is my default browser), but I think it might also be useful for anybody else having the same problem to also include the methods for other browsers too, if that's possible.

Comment: @techie007 oh dear, that makes me get afraid this is not possible...

Comment: I agree, I'm not sure there's an answer to be had. :(

Comment: Would editing/deleting a specific cookie be a viable workaround?

Comment: @and31415 anything that would automatically prevent a certain cookie from being stored, accessed, or existing. If it's a small userscript, that's fine; if it's a built-in setting, that'd be great of course. I wouldn't like to have to manually delete the cookie every time I want to reset it though.

Comment: @and31415 could you post the code that worked for you? I am not really able to get it to work.

Comment: @joeytje50 Sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Achievement unlocked - Selective cookie clearing

By default, browsers don't allow such a fine-grained control over cookies: usually you can either block all third-party cookies or block all cookies for a given domain. Blocking everything is not an option because you'll easily end up breaking basic functionality (e.g. user login). In this case you have to resort to userscripts or extensions.

---

## Firefox - userscript solution

This is the code I've come up with. Tested with Firefox 26.0, Greasemonkey 1.14.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        JSFiddlePanelReset
// @namespace   net.jsfiddle.userscripts
// @description Resets panels back to their default size whenever the site is loaded.
// @version     1.0
// @icon        http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png
// @grant       none
// @include     http://jsfiddle.net/*
// @match       http://jsfiddle.net/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function (){

    // set the domain
    var domain = ".jsfiddle.net";

    // get a date in the past
    var expireDate = new Date(-1).toUTCString();

    // clear the size-related cookie and force it to expire
    document.cookie = "window_sizes=; domain=" + domain + "; path=/; expires=" + expireDate;

})();
```

### Remarks

As pointed out by @Brock Adams in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194473/can-greasemonkey-delete-cookies-from-a-given-domain), there are major limitations on what Greasemonkey can delete:

> - The cookies you want to delete are on the current page's domain.
> - They are not ["Secure cookies"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly).
> - The cookie path (which cannot be detected by Greasemonkey) is the default path, `/`.
> - No cookies are set by javascript, after the page loads.
> - The thing tracking you really is a "cookie".  Many websites use a variety of other techniques, including LSO's, local storage, etc.

### References

- [JavaScript Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
- [Auto-delete Cookie](http://userscripts.org/topics/20571)
- [Can greasemonkey delete cookies from a given domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194473/can-greasemonkey-delete-cookies-from-a-given-domain#9728016)

---

## Chromium-based browsers - extension

While the above userscript does clear the specified cookie, the JSFiddle panels are not reset for whatever reason. Since that's not the type of browser I use, I didn't invest too much time trying to understand why; maybe someone else can shed some light on this. As an alternative you can use the [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) extension.

### Edit This Cookie

Among other things, this particular extension can block specific cookies. You can filter them by domain, name, and value.

[image: Blocked cookie]

### References

- [Is it possible to block one cookie on a domain](https://superuser.com/questions/706690/is-it-possible-to-block-one-cookie-on-a-domain)

Comment: in case someone looking for a chrome extension that can select multiple cookies, provides one-click quick filters, needs to view all domain cookies of current page then check [StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) cookie manager chrome extension.